# How to inject the @Context when consuming FIQL queries in Apache CXF - JAX-RS?

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to implement a FIQL search queries and I am following the guide at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-advanced-features.html#JAX-RSAdvancedFeatures-FIQLsearchqueries.

The issue is that the SearchContext is always null and I am getting a NullPointerException at runtime.

My sample code is :

```
@Context
private SearchContext searchContext;

@GET
@Path("/actor/")
@Override
public List<Actor> getActorBy() {
    SearchCondition<District> sc =  searchContext.getCondition(Actor.class);
}
```

I am getting the NullPointerException when executing the method getCondition on searchContext.

The others rest calls are working.

Is there a way to inject or configure the SearchContext so I can be able to execute a fiql search query ?

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045353/fiql-searchcontext-throws-nullpointerexception-when-injected-with-context

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problem injecting @Context(s)...  I was able to get this working by

```
 public List<Actor> getActorBy(@Context SearchContext searchContext) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a SearchContextProvider to your jaxrs:server

example:

```
<jaxrs:server id="myWebServices" address="/ws">
        [...]
        <jaxrs:providers>
            [...]
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchContextProvider"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
```