# FIQL SearchContext throws NullPointerException when injected with @Context

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to implement a simple Rest service using **FIQL** but my code throws `NullPointerException` at the point where I inject the `SearchContext` with the `@Context`. Here is my code

My service class:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchCondition;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchContext;

@Path("/search")
public class Books {

    private List<Book> theBooks = new LinkedList<Book>();

    @Path("/book")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Book> getBook(@Context SearchContext searchContext) {

        theBooks.add(new Book("1", "nick1"));
        theBooks.add(new Book("2", "nick2"));
        theBooks.add(new Book("3", "nick3"));
        theBooks.add(new Book("4", "nick4"));
        theBooks.add(new Book("5", "nick5"));

        SearchCondition<Book> condition = searchContext
                .getCondition(Book.class);

        return condition.findAll(theBooks);
    }
}
```

My Book class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Book {

    private String id;
    private String author;

    public Book(){  }
    public Book(String id, String ownerinfo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.author = ownerinfo;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getOwnerinfo() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setOwnerinfo(String ownerinfo) {
        this.author = ownerinfo;
    } 
}
```

I am using maven and I have used the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-search</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

According to this [CXF-4949](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/jira-Resolved-CXF-4949-FIQL-searchContext-returns-null-SearchCondition-td5726441.html) my code (I believe) should work but I still the `searchContext` is null after the `@Context`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this out. I was missing the declaration of the `SearchContextProvider` in the `beans.xml` file. I just added the line

```
<bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchContextProvider"/>
```

in the `<jaxrs:providers>` tag and now it works fine.

More about FIQL [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-search.html)

Thanks